# Data cleaning sentiment analysis

Tags: algorithm, matlab, sentiment-analysis

Lets say we have a vector (input):

```
v = ["apple", "man", "ship", " man", " apple"]
```

The desired output should look something like:

```
y = [[1,5],[2,4]]
```

Essentially `y` is an array of arrays that contains indices for words that differ by a "space" character (e.g. "apple" and " apple").

Any suggestions on how this can be done in MATLAB?

Comment: `y = [[1,5],[2,4]]` is equivalent to `y = [1, 5, 2, 4]`. Are you sure this is the result that you want?

Comment: I'm sorry should have made it clear, I was looking for y to be a 2D array. @gnovice's post solved it!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you want `y` to be a 2-D array where each row contains the indices for a string followed by its space-padded version. You can do that using the functions [`strip`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strip.html) (or [`strtrim`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtrim.html)), [`setdiff`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html), and [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) like so:

```
[strWithSpace, index1] = setdiff(v, strip(v));
[~, index2] = ismember(strip(strWithSpace), v);
y = [index2(:) index1(:)];
```

And the result for your sample case:

```
y =

     1     5
     2     4
```

Note that the above will work equally well for a [string array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-string-arrays.html) as it will for a [cell array of character arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/cell-arrays-of-strings.html). So, your input could be either of the following:

```
v = ["apple", "man", "ship", " man", " apple"];
v = {'apple', 'man', 'ship', ' man', ' apple'};
```